# Генерирование расклада карт

Tags: алгоритм, случайные-числа

*Вообще можно взять любой пример на случайную растасовку, но этот пример самой красочный. Да и имеет свои особенности*

Для уложения задачи будем считать, что у нас **105 разных карт**. **Их нужно раздать на 5 рук/игроков/людей (20 карт на руку) + 5 карт отложить отдельно в так называемый прикуп (иногда встречается в карт. играх)**

**Время работы:** незаметно для пользователя (т.е примерно **>1 секунды**)

Если кто-то будет прилагать код, чтобы не писать лишнее, будем считать, что у нас уже есть неотсортированный массив cards[] со всеми 105 картами

Comment: Обратите внимание, что когда все быстро:

    Наконец, следует заметить, что даже использование прекрасного генератора, изъян в алгоритме может возникнуть из-за неправильного использования генератора. Представим себе, например, что реализация алгоритма на языке Java создает новый генератор для каждого вызова процесса тасования без задания параметров в конструкторе. Для инициализации генератора будет использовано текущее время (System.currentTimeMillis()). Таким образом, два вызова с разницей во времени менее миллисекунды дадут идентичные перестановки.


из вики про алгоритм Саттоло и прочих.

Comment: Это вопрос плохого дизайна программы, к алгоритму Саттоло никакого отношения не имеющий. Он даже к Java прямого отношения не имеет. ГПСЧ должен быть инициализирован один раз за всё время жизни программы.

Answer (score 3):

[Алгоритм Саттоло](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%E2%80%93%D0%99%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%B0#.D0.90.D0.BB.D0.B3.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.BC_.D0.A1.D0.B0.D1.82.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.BB.D0.BE).

Comment: @VadimTukaev, а почему именно Саттоло, а не алгоритм Фишера-Йетса, рассматриваемый там же?

В чем, на Ваш взгляд, его превосходство.

Comment: Строго говоря, он хуже (в вакууме). Он всегда меняет элемент на другой, хотя очевидно, что должен существовать шанс, что карта останется на прежнем месте. Поэтому, если мы каждый раз инициализируем колоду (от 0 до 104), а потом мешаем, то надо использовать алгоритм Дурштенфельда.

Однако для ситуации, когда новая колода получается перемешиванием старой (тоже перемешанной), Саттоло вполне применим, ИМХО. Тем более для карточной игры, где не так важна конкретная позиция карты, как ее попадание конкретному игроку. Например, комбинация "три туза" не зависит от порядка, в каком игрок получал тузов

Comment: @avp, изначально у Фишера-Йетса сложность O(n^2) и перетасовка в новый массив, а не тот же, поэтому наверное правильнее брать алгоритм Дурштенфельда. А вот разницу между алгоритмами Саттоло и Дурштенфельда на конечном множестве я никак уловить не могу, кроме разных отрезков которые не существенны вроде, сколько не перечитываю.

Comment: Проще всего объяснить на примере. Допустим, есть массив {1, 2, 3}. Перемешиваем. Какова вероятность, что получится опять {1, 2, 3}?

В случае Дурштенфельда - 1/6. В случае Саттоло - 0. Каждый конкретный элемент никогда не занимает то же самое место, что и раньше. Поэтому мы получим не n!, а (n-1)! = 2 перестановки: {2, 3, 1} и {3, 1, 2}.

Comment: Спасибо, так понятнее, у Саттоло выходит обязательная перестановка элемента на новое место.

Comment: Да, написав Фишера я имел в виду, конечно, Дурштенфельда. 

Просто мне показалось, что в обсуждении этих алгоритмов (в статье в вики) старую версию Фишера (O(n^2)) вообще не рассматривают (соответственно  вместо Дурштенфельд говорят Фишер).

--

Возможно, ошибаюсь. Не слишком вчитывался, идеи-то там очевидные.

Answer (score 0):

Все таки мне больше нравится способ с выбором случайной карты из колоды с удалением из массива, он довольно простой и, что не мало важно, наглядный. На языке JavaScript элементарно и просто:

```
var player1 = [],
    player2 = [],
    player3 = [],
    player4 = [],
    player5 = [],
    realCardsArray = [];

for(i=0;i<105;i++) realCardsArray.push(i);

function get_random_card(cardArray){
    return cardArray.splice(Math.ceil(Math.random()*cardArray.length-1),1);
}

for(i=0;i<20;i++){
    player1.push(get_random_card(realCardsArray));
    player2.push(get_random_card(realCardsArray));
    player3.push(get_random_card(realCardsArray));
    player4.push(get_random_card(realCardsArray));
    player5.push(get_random_card(realCardsArray));
}
```

P.S. Хотел сделать комментарием, но не хватает места на форматирование.

Comment: Он просто медленный, по сравнению с тасованием на месте.

Comment: Сложность квадратичная. Имеет право на жизнь, только если карт очень немного.

Comment: Да, он медленный, но у него есть некоторые интересные особенности, которые могут пригодится:

1. Фактически никакой перетасовки на самом деле не происходит, а просто реализуется доступ таким образом, как будто карты уже перетасованы. Если требуется получить не полный набор, а только часть рандомизированных данных в относительно продолжительных отрезках времени, этот подход может дать выигрыш как "отложенные вычисления".

2. Именно в такой реализации он хорошо ложится на объектную модель, если мы взяли карту из колоды, то мы действительно взяли карту из колоды и дали кому-то, ее там больше нет

Answer (score -1):

Мои варианты:

1.**10 раз быстрой сортировкой.** *(тупой, но лёгкий способ)*

Т.е взять cards[] и отсортировать его. Только метод, выполняющий сортировку, будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
Card.compareTo(Object o) {
   if(Math.random < 0.5) return 1; else return -1;
}
```

Ну а потом то что в массиве на 0-19 считать первой рукой, 20-39 - второй, и т.д.

2.**Генерировать номер места для карты** *(самый оптимальный для меня)*

Т.е. по очереди брать карты и генерировать для неё номер позиции. Если этот номер уже занят, ставить карту на следующую, занята следующая - на позаследующую и т.д.

3.**Брать случайных по очереди** *(2ой самый оптимальный для меня)*

1) Превращаем cards в динамический массив
2) Берём рандомную карту и удаляем из динамического массива
3) ставим первой ещё один новый массив
4) Берём ещё одну рандомную и ставим следующей в новый массив из пункта 3, и так пока карты не кончатся

4.**Collections.shuffle()** из java (узнал о нём во время составления вопроса)

Comment: Так вот откуда берутся жутко тормознутые программы, жрущие гигабайты памяти на тривиальнейших задачах.

Comment: @VadimTukaev,
 
1. худш o(150^2 * 10)
2. в среднем не больше o(150*30)
3. log(300)
4. хз

Это достаточно быстро

Comment: Речь не о данной конкретной задаче, речь о двух разных подходах к решению задач. Я сначала вникаю в задачу и пытаюсь найти или создать максимально подходящий алгоритм. Вы берёте какой-нибудь алгоритм и пытаетесь приспособить к задаче. http://habrahabr.ru/post/153225/

Comment: @VadimTukaev, я вникаю в задачу и думаю, что бы применить для её решения. Чтоб написать побыстрее. И то, в данном случае это относится только к первому пункту. 

p.s.Статья хорошая, но совсем не в тему

Comment: В тему, Вы просто не поняли аналогии. Ну да ладно, проехали.

Маленькое воспоминание из детства. Конкурс в компьютерном журнале. Есть процедура на ассемблере, занимает 36 байт. Надо реализовать её короче. Победитель (это был не я) с помощью хитрых трюков, основанных на побочных эффектах логических операций, уложился в 33 байта.

Comment: НИКОГДА не делайте так, как в 1. Функция сравнения должна быть детерменированной, иначе вы рискуете сломать алгоритм сортировки. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962802/is-it-correct-to-use-javascript-array-sort-method-for-shuffling

Comment: Продолжу:
2. Мат. ожидание числа шагов в вашем алгоритме:

![alt][1]

где ψ^(0) -- это [Дигамма-функция][2], которая асимптотически равна ln(x). T.е. сложность равна O(ln(N)*N^2).
3. Сложность O(N^2).

Единственный здравый совет в вашем ответе, это использовать Collections.shuffle().
Однозначно минус.

  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/FfyZiuT.gif
  [2]: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: @danpetruk, ну и записи вида O(const) не показывают ничего, т.к. O(const) == O(1).